# A Fundamental Query about Inheritance using two classes in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

Kindly consider the following code in Java:

```
class a
{
    int i = 10;
    int j = 20;
}

class b extends a
{
    int i = 100;
    int j = 200;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        a a1 = new a();
        b b1 = new b();
        a1 = b1;
        System.out.println("a1.i is " + a1.i);
        System.out.println("a1.j is " + a1.j);
        System.out.println("b1.i is " + b1.i);
        System.out.println("b1.j is " + b1.j);

    }
}
```

The output I get is

```
a1.i is 10
a1.j is 20
b1.i is 100
b1.j is 200
```

My query is: Why does the statement a1=b1 not change a1.i to 100 and a1.j to 200? Does the statement a1 = b1 change nothing?

Comment: Also ask yourself what happens when you try `a a1 = new a(); a b1 = new b(); b1 = a1;`.

Comment: fields are not inherited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're upcasting an instance of class `B` to an instance of class `A`.

After performing

```
a1 = b1
```

then you technically can't access fields of `b1` through the variable `a1`. That's because `a1`, whether or not it "comes" from the assignment of `b1`, is effectively an instance of the class `A` after you **upcasted** it.

Consider this: the fact that you defined one instance of the fields `i` and `j` in both class `A` and class `B` does not mean they are at all related.

I think you meant to do the following (conceptually):

```
class A {
    int i;
    int j;
    public A() {
        i = 10;
        j = 20;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        i = 100;
        j = 200;
    }
}
```

Then try this

```
A a1 = new A();
B b1 = new B();
a1 = b1;
System.out.println("a1.i is " + a1.i); // 100
System.out.println("a1.j is " + a1.j); // 200
System.out.println("b1.i is " + b1.i); // 100
System.out.println("b1.j is " + b1.j); // 200
```

If you do this, then class `B` is setting the field that is inherited from class `A`. At that point, you'll get your expected behavior. This is because even if you downcast an instance of `B` to an instance of `A`, you are always mutating a field that is inherited from `A`, as opposed to `B` in your current example.

Comment: isn't A the superclass?thereby **upcasting b1**?

Comment: Your tweaking of the code doesn't change the answer. The output is still the same.

Comment: You should try again. Notice how B doesn't define any instance variables

Answer (score 1):

Instances of `a` have fields `i` (10) and `j` (20).

Instances of `b` have those fields that `a` has, and two more fields, also confusingly called `i` and `j`, with values 100 and 200.

So `b1` has `{ a::i=10, a::j=20, b::i=100, b::j=200 }`.

If you access `b1.i` you get the `b::i` field from object `b1` (as you would expect).

Your `a1` variable is of type `a` (even if it holds an instance of `b`), so you can only access fields of `a` with it. So if you access `a1.i`, you get the `a::i` field from the object (which is 10), rather than the `b::i` field (which is 100).

Answer (score 1):

Be ready because the question you asked requires a complicated answer.

Java is run in a Jave Virtual Machine.In the context of your question,there are 2 things you need to remember about java and the JVM.

1. Java methods are a run time bindings

   - Java typecasting(and boxing,unboxing) are runtime binding
2. Java class parameters are compile time bindings

   - Java casting will give you errors **if and only if** the . casting is logically incorrect.

Now lets analyse your code.

```
    a a1 = new a();
    b b1 = new b();
    //This type cast happens a Runtime and not compile time although the check is done at compile time and your code passes the check!
    a1 = b1;
    //These variables are binded at compile.And hence possess the value
 that they possesed during compie time.This means that they have 
the original values which they were defined with
    System.out.println("a1.i is " + a1.i);
    System.out.println("a1.j is " + a1.j);
    System.out.println("b1.i is " + b1.i);
    System.out.println("b1.j is " + b1.j);
```

Now to indicate the impact and modification of this,add this to your code and test it.

```
class Test{
     public static void main(String args[])
        {
            a a1 = new a();
            b b1 = new b();
            a1 = b1;
            System.out.println("a1.i is " + a1.i);
            System.out.println("a1.j is " + a1.j);
            System.out.println("b1.i is " + b1.i);
            System.out.println("b1.j is " + b1.j);

            a1.print();
            //shall print b
            b1.print();
            //shall print b
        }

}   
}

class a
{
    int i = 10;
    int j = 20;

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}

class b extends a
{
    int i = 100;
    int j = 200;
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("b");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:Searched hard for a well written SO answer for the differnce but did not come accross any.So [this tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html) explains this concept quite well.